# leaflet.js returning my ajax json data as an array with coordinates

Tags: php, ajax, json, leaflet

How do i take my coordinates from my array and put them into markers on my leaflet map? Here's my code:

```
<div id="map">

<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.76, -98.5], 4); 
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map); 



    $(document).ready(function(){   
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',     
  dataType: "json",
  url: '<?php echo matry::base_to('tests/map_it');?>',
  success: function (data) 
  {

//alert (data[0].first + " " + data[0].last + " " + data[0].trainer_address1 + ", " + data[0].CITY + " " + data[0].STATE);

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    document.write(data[i].first + ' ' + data[i].last + " " + data[i].trainer_address1 + ", " + data[i].CITY + " " + data[i].STATE + '<br />');

}

  }

  });
});

</script>


<?php
spl_autoload_register('autoload_lib');
// $mapit = sql::results("Select * from event.ACS.trainer where inactive is null or inactive=0");
// foreach ($mapit as $row)
// {
    // $return[] = json_encode($row, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// }
// echo json_encode($return);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$mapit = sql::results("Select * from event.ACS.trainer where inactive is null or inactive=0");
foreach ($mapit as $row)
{
    $return[] = $row;
}
//echo json_encode($return);

$array = array(array('addr1'=>'$data', 'city'=>'Carlsbad', 'state'=>'CA'),array('addr1'=>'42 Mer Gn', 'city'=>'dido', 'state'=>'CA'));

foreach ($array as $addr)
{
    $mapit = new MapIt($addr);
    print_r($mapit->send_request());
}
```

This is the last step but I can't figure it out. Leaflet accepts coordinates and not addresses so I've converted my addresses to coordinates already. Would appreciate some guidance on this question. Thank you.

```
Array
(
    [lat] => 33.158099
    [lng] => -117.349701
)
Array
(
    [lat] => 33.119202
    [lng] => -117.085602
)
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: updated flux! Once again, thanks for helping out, you're always helping me with this leaflet.